# Microsoft Excel - Find Percentage of Total for Multiple Different Total Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find the percentage of the total for each group in a set of data (each group has its own total, and multiple values that are used to find a % of the total). Is there a way to do this easily using Excel functions?

Here is an example:
[image: Example spreadsheet]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(B1/VLOOKUP("Total "&IFERROR(MID(A1,LEN("value ")+1,FIND(".",A1)-LEN("value ")-1),""),A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]